# InceptionResNetV2 validation accuracy stuck around 20% to 30%

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to train a CNN to classify 9 class of image. Each class has 1000 image for training. I tried training on VGG16 and VGG19, both can achieve validation accuracy of 90%. But when I tried to train on InceptionResNetV2 model, the model seems to stuck around 20% and 30%. Below is my code for InceptionResNetV2 and the training. What can I do to improve the training?

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3),weights = 'imagenet',include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
base_model,
Flatten(),
Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4),
Dropout(0.5),
BatchNormalization(),
Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4),
Dense(9, activation = 'softmax')])

optimizer_model = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, name='Adam', decay=0.00001)
loss_model = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer_model, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

Epoch 1/10
899/899 [==============================] - 255s 283ms/step - loss: 4.3396 - acc: 0.3548 - val_loss: 4.2744 - val_acc: 0.3874
Epoch 2/10
899/899 [==============================] - 231s 257ms/step - loss: 3.5856 - acc: 0.4695 - val_loss: 3.9151 - val_acc: 0.3816
Epoch 3/10
899/899 [==============================] - 225s 250ms/step - loss: 3.1451 - acc: 0.4959 - val_loss: 4.8801 - val_acc: 0.2425
Epoch 4/10
899/899 [==============================] - 227s 252ms/step - loss: 2.7771 - acc: 0.5124 - val_loss: 3.7167 - val_acc: 0.3023
Epoch 5/10
899/899 [==============================] - 231s 257ms/step - loss: 2.4993 - acc: 0.5260 - val_loss: 3.7276 - val_acc: 0.3770
Epoch 6/10
899/899 [==============================] - 227s 252ms/step - loss: 2.3148 - acc: 0.5251 - val_loss: 3.7677 - val_acc: 0.3115
Epoch 7/10
899/899 [==============================] - 234s 260ms/step - loss: 2.1381 - acc: 0.5379 - val_loss: 3.4867 - val_acc: 0.2862
Epoch 8/10
899/899 [==============================] - 230s 256ms/step - loss: 2.0091 - acc: 0.5367 - val_loss: 4.1032 - val_acc: 0.3080
Epoch 9/10
899/899 [==============================] - 225s 251ms/step - loss: 1.9155 - acc: 0.5399 - val_loss: 4.1270 - val_acc: 0.2954
Epoch 10/10
899/899 [==============================] - 232s 258ms/step - loss: 1.8349 - acc: 0.5508 - val_loss: 4.3918 - val_acc: 0.2276
```

Comment: There are some ways to improve accuracy. What is your dataset about? Is it similar to imagenet dataset like domain similarity?

Comment: My dataset is on medical domain, classifying medical image view. I tried to add one more fully connected layer to my ANN, the accuracy seems to improve by 10%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VGG-16/19 has a depth of 23/26 layers, whereas, InceptionResNetV2 has a depth of 572 layers. Now, there is minimal domain similarity between medical images and imagenet dataset. In VGG, due to low depth the features you're getting are not that complex and network is able to classify it on the basis of Dense layer features. However, in IRV2 network, as it's too much deep, the output of the *fc* layer is more complex (visualize it something object like but for imagenet dataset), and, then the features obtained from these layers are unable to connect to the Dense layer features, and, hence overfitting. I think you were able to get my point.

Check out my answer to very similar question of yours on this link: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330597/accuracy-low-on-validation-set-using-vgg16/62358774#62358774). It will help improve your accuracy.