# Why my NASNet model's accuracy not improving during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have customized the following model in keras, however, when I am training, the model's accuracy is barely increasing:

```
from keras.applications.nasnet import NASNetLarge
from keras.optimizers import SGD

base_model = NASNetLarge(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

x = base_model.layers[-6].output
x = Flatten(name='FLATTEN')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='last_FC1')(x)  # let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dropout(0.5, name='DROPOUT')(x) # Dropout layer so the visualisations are done properly
predictions = Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax', name='PREDICTIONS')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in model.layers[:-290]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

FYI, The training accuracy, training loss, validation accuracy and validation loss is as follows:

> epoch |   accuracy |  loss |  val_accuracy |  val_loss
>
> 0 |   0.5149105 | 60.32275529 |   0.463636369 |   0.693147182
>
> 1 |   0.51292247 |    0.693200452 |   0.53694582 |    0.695120037
>
> 2 |   0.528827 |  0.692723821 |   0.532019675|    0.689894736
>
> 3 |   0.53677934 |    0.692179034 |   0.551724136 |   0.695185542
>
> 4 |   0.53479123 |    0.69184255 |    0.453201979 |   0.696151495
>
> 5 |   0.54075545 |    0.69120561 |    0.571428597 |   0.693781257
>
> 6 |   0.5149105 | 0.69272005| 0.541871905 |   0.70132494
>
> 7 |   0.528827 |  0.69375147 |    0.566502452 |   0.693984807

Can someone suggest which variables should I change in the aforementioned code to improve the training?

How to know which variables to modify in a Keras model to improve the model's training?

Comment: Can you print the train val accuracy? NASNEt Large is a huge network, have you tried efficientnet? Checkout my answer to improve accuracy on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330597/accuracy-low-on-validation-set-using-vgg16/62358774#62358774)

Comment: I have not tried efficient net for keras. do u know how I can import efficient net from keras (not the TensorFlow version) because using 'from keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB7' throws an error. @AkashKumar and also, validation accuracy decreased over time for each epoch.

Comment: pip install from this github repo. It works fine https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet